# FileVersion is not getting populated correctly in uninstaller

Tags: install4j

I use two different compiler variable to generate fileVersion e.g.
**${compiler:version1}.0.${compiler:version2}** 
where
version1 = 1.0 and version2=12000

Installer generates fine with file version 1.0.0.12000

But when I use the same value on uninstaller, It ignores it completely (I have *Customized Version info* checked in both cases) and picks version from General Settings. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed in the current build:

- http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_windows_5_0_11.exe
- http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_windows-x64_5_0_11.exe
- http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_unix_5_0_11.tar.gz
- http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_macos_5_0_11.dmg

Comment: This is great, are there a release notes for this version?

Comment: when is the ETA on final build (5.0.11)